# XML writer with repeating elements in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js, serialization

I'm trying to serialize an XML from a given object in node.js. I would like to serialize an array as some elements with the same name, i.e. the same element should be repeated.

Example:

```
var objectToSerialize = {
    SomeElement: {
        Data: [3, 5, 2]
    }
};
serialize(objectToSerialize);
```

Requested result:

```
<RootElement>
    <SomeElement>
        <Data>3</Data>
        <Data>5</Data>
        <Data>2</Data>
    </SomeElement>
</root>
```

I tried xml2js, but the result is:

```
<root>
    <SomeElement>
        <0>3</0>
        <1>5</1>
        <2>2</2>
    </SomeElement>
</root>
```

And I didn't find option to make it like that.

Which library can serialize such XML?

Notes:

- The question is mainly about how to OUTPUT such XML, I have the freedom to define the input format (for example, I may decide that serializing such XML will occur when a Uint8Array is passed instead of array, etc.).
- The array contains only numbers.
- Richer libraries to write XML are prefered as I need some more features which might be special (like writing xmlns attributes).

**Edit:** Not like the input, this is of high priority that the structure of the array in the output XML will match the exact example I gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whom it may concern, I ended up with "xml": https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml

It only requires changing the input into:

```
var objectToSerialize = [{
    SomeElement: [
        { Data: 3 },
        { Data: 5 },
        { Data: 2 }
    ]
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this libary [xml-mapping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-mapping)

```
var XMLMapping = require('xml-mapping');
var objectToSerialize = {
    SomeElement: {
        Data: [3, 5, 2]
    }
};

console.log(XMLMapping.dump(objectToSerialize));
```

The output is:

```
<SomeElement>
   <Data><![CDATA[3]]></Data>
   <Data><![CDATA[5]]></Data>
   <Data><![CDATA[2]]></Data>
</SomeElement>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your link is broken, remove the dot. Does it support plotting the data without the CDATA section?